# Invalid JSON Expression

Tags: json, api, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am making use of non-static import

```
JsonPath jp = response.jsonPath();
System.out.println(jp.get("data?(@.id>14).employee_name").toString());
```

For a JSON as shown below:

```
{"status":"success","data":[{"id":"1","employee_name":"Tiger Nixon","employee_salary":"320800","employee_age":"61","profile_image":""},{"id":"2","employee_name":"Garrett Winters","employee_salary":"170750","employee_age":"63","profile_image":""}]}
```

When i am trying to run it , i am getting below error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
    Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found '[' @ line 1, column 31.
                                data[?(@.id>14)].employee_name
                                 ^

1 error
```

Can someone guide me why is this error being thrown ?

Comment: Rest Assured uses `GPath` which is not a `JSONPath` you might know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt if that syntax is right, nonetheless, you should be using the below

Also note that the id is a string in your response so you will have to include it in quotes

```
js.get("data.find {it.id > '14'}.employee_name").toString();
```

Comment: With this syntax, i am getting the below error                 :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "it" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function

Comment: Are you sure ? Cause this is a working example for the same json you've posted, can you post your complete code ?

Comment: Here it is :     Response resp = RestAssured.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
  System.out.println(resp.getStatusCode());
  Assert.assertEquals(resp.getStatusCode(), 200);
  JsonPath jp = resp.jsonPath();
  System.out.println(jp.get("data.employee_name").toString());
  System.out.println(jp.get("data.id").toString());
  System.out.println(jp.get("data.find(it.id > '14').employee_name").toString());

Comment: There's a mistake in your code, Its supposed to be `{it.id > '14'}` and not `(it.id > '14')`